# Use Mysql assoc() to pass data to a flutter table

Tags: flutter, dart

With this code I read all the rows that will then have to be displayed in a flutter table. Each row consists of 34 columns[1] and, in my opinion, the simplest system is to use row.assoc()
My problem is how to exploit this possibility using jsondecode and then pass it all to the table.
Or should I read row.colByName("xxx")); from mysql and then insert it in the display table

[1] mysql table consists of the columns "name", "year","month", "d1"..."d31"

```
Future<List<UserModel>> getmySQLData() async {
  var anno = '2023';
  var mese = '7';
  
  final connected = await MySQLConnection.createConnection(
     // connection data
     );

  await connected.connect();
  var result;

  try {
    result = await connected.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM `alldata` WHERE anno = :year AND mese = :month",
        {"year": anno, "month": mese});
  } on Exception catch (_) {
    print("Mysql error");
    //exit(1);
  }

  //final List<UserModel> mylist = [];
  final List<Map> thelist = [];
```